# How can i connect futronic fs64 to my flutter code

Tags: flutter, biometrics

I want to capture 10 fingers as image and store my database as base64 using flutter code.
I have futronic fs64 and I have installed driver to my computer and don't have any idea about how i use it in my flutter project.
Any one has an idea please help me it's necessary for me.